# Overwrite ConnectionString in web.config ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, connection-string

I'm trying to encrypt parts of my web.config file.(Passwords)
This works fine for normal Section-Keys like that:

```
<AppSettings>
    <add key="SomePassword" value="HI I AM ENCRYPTET"/>
<AppSettings>
```

In the Global.asax i do the following:

`System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomePassword"] = Decrypt(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomePassword"])`

This works fine. But when I try this for the Connection-String, an exception is thrown: "The configuration is read only."

So, I have no right to write. Does somebody know how to solve this without editing the Connection-String class?

Thanks & Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can move secrets out of your web.config file via:

```
<appSettings file="..\..\AppSettingsSecrets.config">
```

See Best practices for deploying passwords and other sensitive data to ASP.NET and Azure Websites. http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure

For Azure, I like to use http://www.powershellcookbook.com/recipe/PukO/securely-store-credentials-on-disk to encrypt credentials to disk.